# Activeadmin Batch actions button grayed out and check boxes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am kind of new to rails. I am setting up the activeadmin but on the record list for a model the batch actions and check boxes are having issues. Basically the batch actions button is grayed out and when I click the top check box to select/unselect all records it just checks that one box, all other boxes remain with the current state they have, making it not possible to apply any batch actions.

I know that by default there is a delete batch action but with the button grayed out I cannot know.

The solutions I've tried so far are:

Add the `selectable_column` option on the `app/admin/model.rb`

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :name
  column :email
  column :create_date
  actions
end
```

And add `#= require active_admin/base` to `active_admin.js.coffee`

None of these seem to work. I have seen other rails projects where this batch actions work by default from the beginning, but I cannot restart a new project because I am far to advanced on this one.

If any further info is required to solve the issue please let me know.

UPDATE

I see that working projects of active admin have an `assets/active_admin.js` file, my project does not have it. I checked that under sources on the inspector of Chrome. I think that is the problem, but I do not know why it is not loading.

Comment: What's your ActiveAdmin version? So do you have `active_admin.js` file in your project?

Comment: Check my answer, I solved it successfully with the solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems to be a jQuery issue, to solve it you have to migrate old jquery features to your current version, due to the explanation you gave above it seems you are using jQuery 3.

If you’re running into a problem toggling all checkboxes in index page for batch action in Active Admin you should:

1. Download [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)
2. Added it as asset and require it in `active_admin.js` manifest file

   `//= require jquery-migrate`

[Source](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4864)